# Why is the CSS animation freezing in my snippet?

Tags: css

I have applied this html code to a Text Module and the Text Module turn out in 5 Columns.
I applied the CSS animation and the animation is working fine in Editor but in the website not working on the Post when in the visitor mode.
When i edit the Post in Drag and Drop editor then the Code is working fine when i hover on the Box it animate but not in Visitor mode when i open the page in another browser as Visitor.The post is showing, Columns is showing, but no animation.

```css
   .bg-box {
        height: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;
        background: transparent;
    }
    
    .sol-1 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .sol-2 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 100px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .sol-3 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 200px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .sol-4 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 300px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    .sol-5 {
        top: 8px;
        left: 400px; 
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
    
    [class^="sol"] {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .sol-1:hover ~ .bg-box {
      -webkit-animation-name: background-sol-1 !important;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s !important; 
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards !important;
    }
    
    .sol-2:hover ~ .bg-box {
      -webkit-animation-name: background-sol-2;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
    
    .sol-3:hover ~ .bg-box {
      -webkit-animation-name: background-sol-3;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .sol-4:hover ~ .bg-box {
      -webkit-animation-name: background-sol-4;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    .sol-5:hover ~ .bg-box {
      -webkit-animation-name: background-sol-5;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
      -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes background-sol-1 {
        0% {
            background: transparent;
        }
        100% {
            background: black;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes background-sol-2 {
        0% {
             background-color: transparent;
        }
        100% {
             background: red;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes background-sol-3 {
        0% {
             background: transparent;
        }
        100% {
             background: blue;;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes background-sol-4 {
        0% {
             background: transparent;
        }
        100% {
             background: green;;
        }
    }
    @-webkit-keyframes background-sol-5 {
        0% {
             background: transparent;
        }
        100% {
             background: pink;;
        }
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <body>
    <div class="sol-1"></div>
    <div class="sol-2"></div>
    <div class="sol-3"></div>
    <div class="sol-4"></div>
    <div class="sol-5"></div>
    <div class="bg-box">
    </div>
```

Comment: Editor / Visitor , are those roles in your application??

Comment: what are : `text module`, `editor`,`post`, `visitor mode` ? things not related to CSS for sure

Comment: yes i edit the animation and it works perfectly when i am in editor mode, i applied changes to save. >> Success.>> i click to view page and then the page open in another tab as a visitor, the post is shown but the animation is not active when i hover.

Comment: editor i mean the drop and drag post editor.